# Let $U,V\subset \mathbb R^n$ is there a function $f:U\to V$ continuous, bijective s.t. $f^{-1}$ is not continuous.

Tags: general-topology

Let $U,V\subset \mathbb R^n$. Is there a function $f:U\to V$ continuous, bijective s.t. $f^{-1}$ is not continuous ? I didn't find any, do you have an example or it's impossible ?

Comment: Are $U$ and $V$ both open or both closed or can they be anything?

Comment: You can prove that there is no counter-example over $\mathbb{R}^1$. That suggests that any counter-example must make use of loops in higher dimensions. Try that!

Comment: @Rise: anything...

Answer (score 2):

Let $U \subset \mathbb R$ be any countable discrete set, for example $U = \{1,2,3, \ldots \}$ and let $V = \mathbb Q$ be the rational numbers. Observe both sets are countable. Then since $U$ is discrete any bijection $f \colon U \to V$ will be continuous (the preimage of any set at all is open). But $f$ being continuous would imply that $\mathbb Q$ has the discrete topology. Which is untrue.

Answer (score 2):

In $\mathbb {R}^2$ take $U =[0,1)\times \{0\}$ $V=S^1$ and $f$ to be the function given by $(t, 0) \mapsto e^{2\pi it}$. This is continuous bijective but $f^{-1}$ is not continuous.